# UIImageView stretch "issue"?

Tags: ios, swift, uiimageview, uipickerviewcontroller

I have 2 view controllers.

> **View controller 1**: UIImagePickerController(to select and crop image)
>   UIImageView(to show image), Button(to upload image to parse). UIImageView size is width 310 x height 300.
>
> **View controller 2**: UIImageView(to show image from parse). UIImageView size is width 310 x height 300.

Both the imageView´s are using this code:

```
imageView.clipsToBounds = true
imageView.contentMode = UIViewContentMode.ScaleToFill
```

I also see in parse.com if i download the image to my MAC, the dimensions are 750x750.

Images for preview:

> Image 1: http://s29.postimg.org/3nlzrhc4n/img1.png Image 2:
>   http://s3.postimg.org/6nr1v9q43/img2.png Image3:
>   http://s29.postimg.org/ixluyo7mv/img3.png

So, how can i make the UIImageView in View Controller 1 and 2 to the same size as the UIImagePickerController editor view?

Comment: do u want to change the height of the imageview ? is that what u r asking ?

Comment: are talking about picker image size or image view size ?

Comment: did u try aspect fit the image instead of scale to fil ?

Comment: @Mr.T I want the image to fit perfect in a imageview without stretching.

Comment: did u try aspect fit mode ? scale fil stretches the image but aspect fit , doesnt stretch the image .

Comment: @Mr.T Yes, i tried AspectFit, but then it does not fill the whole UICollectionViewCell: http://s24.postimg.org/664djnjol/Screen_Shot_2015_11_26_at_17_57_46.png

Comment: constrain the image view to the cell, and try again

Comment: @Mr.T Still not working.. http://s28.postimg.org/rms5zczlp/Screen_Shot_2015_11_26_at_18_06_25.png